# Poner una imagen estática cuando una cámara IP esta deshabilitada

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, stream

Tengo el embedded de un streaming de una cámara IP que debo colocar en un sitio web y necesito que cuando la cámara esta desactivada o apagada, se muestre una imagen estática predeterminada usando JS como lo hacen en esta web [Camaras Viales](https://camarasvialescr.com/)

Como el embedded se genera por iframe no puedo editar directamente el código.

Comment: Podrías utilizar JS y hacer un pedido (externo al iframe) a la dirección del streaming para verificar que el video esté disponible. Dependiendo de este request entonces decidirías si cambiar el iframe por una imagen. Se dificulta de gran manera ayudarte si no compartes el código de tu implementación.

Comment: desde js, deberías tener acceso directo al iframe, así como validar cuando este cargado y su contenido.

Comment: Mónica, lo mejor es que des el primer paso: como pensaste hacerlo y coloques el código para que podamos ayudarte. Es muy difícil saber como ayudarte si no das ese primer paso compartiendo el código en cuestión.